# How can I catch touch events in a TV leanback app to show video controls using VideoSupportFragment?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I'm using `VideoSupportFragment` from the `Leanback` library on a device with a touch screen. I want to be able to show the video controls when the screen is touched but I can't figure out how to enable that. Is there some touch or click listener I can hook into? I tried hooking into `surfaceView` but never got the event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your using a leanback app you can catch the touch events by overriding the dispatchTouchEvent method in your activity.

This is assuming your activity extends AppCompatActivity which is a descendant of FragmentActivity.

So in your activity -

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Fragment fragmentById = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_player_container);
    if (fragmentById instanceof BasePlayerFragment) {
        boolean consume = ((BasePlayerFragment) fragmentById).dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        if (consume) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Then in your fragment that extends SupportVideoFragment (BasePlayerFragment in this example) -

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // You can choose to display the SurfaceView once screen is pressed before even waiting for it to be released
    }
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (consumeViewSurface(ev)) {
                    return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private boolean consumeViewSurface(MotionEvent ev) {

    if (mSurfaceView != null) {
        // Do your code here and return true for letting the system know you handled the event.
        return true;
    }

    // If the event didn't get handled return false
    return false;
}
```

Make sure to return true once you've handled the event and false otherwise.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I'll just need to figure out if I can tell it to hide the controls on its own after a while. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear  :). For hiding it after a while you can use a CountDownTimer and in the timer onFinish callback you can hide it.

Comment: My hope is to let the leanback code handle the timeout so that it feels the same as when it is shown by the library itself, hope that makes sense.